# React native function component, recommended practice to write data to localDB upon app close

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

i have a usecase to write data onto localDB, using AsyncStorage, to add a few key-value pairs.

I tried using the cleanup hook offered by react-native, but, it doesn't get invoked when app is closed on current screen.

Using AppState to determine current state worked, but, i am looking to see if there is a recommended practice to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.